# Как можно перевести "imageware" на русский?

Tags: терминология

Есть похожие слова, это hardware и software. Как перевести их достаточно очевидно, но imageware?

Comment: не могли бы вы разъяснить что это слово значит на английском?

Comment: Перевод зависит от контекста, которого нет.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен контекст для перевода. Вообще это торговая марка,  вид программного обеспечения, в оригинале вроде бы Canon.  Если и становится нарицательным, то только в очень  специфическом контексте, устойчивого перевода в некоторых случаях нет.

Hardware может означать любое оборудование, детали, скобяной товар и прочие технические  аналоги (durable equipment, gear, paraphernalia, equipment). Hardware - это не только оборудование, но  замок для двери, коробка гвоздей  и снаряжение надетое на Вас. Hardware store в прошлом бы переводилось как скобяная лавка, сейчас скорее это может быть и хозяйственный магазин, и магазин торгующий каким-то оборудованием или инструментом.

Software - это укрепившийся сленг построенный по аналогии с Hardware. Есть еще firmware и wetware - а как ЭТО вы переведете? wetware в оригинале было придумано фантастами для обозначения биологических машин или имплантатов, а сейчас так иногда обозначают все продукты биоинженерии. Vaporware - единственное слово из этого семейства, переводимое однозначно: "мыльный пузырь", фиктивный, несуществующий продукт.

Answer (score 0):

***Выбирайте:***

видеометрика

визуальное ПО

система распознавания образов

система визуального распознавания

визуальное оснащение

образ-система

имидж-оборудование

образ-оборудование

система образов

система оптики

система образ-вид